# HTML DropDown List that shows data based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need to create a drop down list that shows you data based on the user's input the data while the user is typing their choice.

The drop down list is way to long and I do not want my users to have to scroll through it.

A good reference for this functionality would be Expedia. When you start typing the name of the city it gives you a list with options to choose from.

Never done this before so any kind of reference or even the name of this type of menu will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using this. Jquery chosen plugin, it has an inbuilt search for the `<select>....</select>` and easy to use

[Chosen Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Answer (score 1):

do this with jQuery + jQuery UI autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/